# I want to check that there should be no NA and the value should be between 0 and 1 in multiple variables in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

This is a small example of a large dataset (3000 columns) I am working on.
I have to figure out how I would check that there are no NA in these columns and the values should be 0 and 1.

```
    col1 <- c(1,0,0,1) 
    col2 <- c(0,0,0,1) 
    col3 <- c(1,0,1,0) 
    col4 <- c(1,1,1,1) 
    col5 <- c(1,NA,1,1)
    
    df <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
```

Comment: When you say 'check (each?) column', do you want the result per-column? i.e. a boolean vector of length 5 (or 3000)?

Comment: Also, should we assume all columns are ints? Checking *"the value should be between 0 and 1"*  on an int is simply `%in% c(1,0)`, whereas on a float requires <= or `between()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I edited your data.frame so we would also have to exclude non-zero/one numeric values.**

```
col1 <- c(1,0,0,1) 
col2 <- c(0,99,0,1) 
col3 <- c(1,0,1,0) 
col4 <- c(1,1,1,99) 
col5 <- c(1,NA,1,1)
df<- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
```

You can loop apply a function that checks whether all elements are either 0 or 1 with the %in% operator (which always returns FALSE when comparing anything to NA).:

```
sapply(df, function(x) all(x %in% c(1,0)))
 col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 
 TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**a simpler solution
with dplyr and purrr:**

```
df%>%summarise_all(~.%in% c(1,0)%>%all)

  col1  col2 col3  col4  col5
1 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you want to do this to a specific selection of columns, you can use `across()`:

```
df%>%summarise(across(1:4, ~.%in% c(1,0)%>%all))
  col1  col2 col3  col4
1 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

**Or just with purrr**

```
map_lgl(df, ~ all(. %in% c(1,0)))
```

Comment: sapply(df, function(x) all(x %in% c(1,0))) ----- How can choose certain variables, for eg., from variable col2 to col4. How can I do that? how can I replace all?

Comment: Thanks, I figured the last part out. Thank you. Big help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `na.omit`, this will return `TRUE` if every non-`NA` column is between 0 and 1:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), list(btw01 = ~ all(na.omit(between(., 0, 1))),
                                      notna = ~all(!is.na(.))))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_sep = "_", names_to = c("Variable", ".value"))
```

**Output**

```
  Variable btw01 notna
  <chr>    <lgl> <lgl>
1 col1     TRUE  TRUE 
2 col2     TRUE  TRUE 
3 col3     TRUE  TRUE 
4 col4     TRUE  TRUE 
5 col5     TRUE  FALSE
```

---

If you don't care which condition is met/fails then you can simplify:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ all(!is.na(.) & between(., 0, 1))))
```

This can be accomplished in base `R` with:

```
sapply(df, function(x) all(!is.na(x) & x >= 0 & x <= 1))
```

**Output**

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4  col5
1 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```